# Unable to launch solution: MyApp is configured to use IIS. The Web server 'http://localhost:64646/' could not be found

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, iis

When trying to launch solution, I receive the following error:

error  : The Web Application Project MyApp is configured to use IIS. The Web server 'http://localhost:64646/' could not be found.

How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I opened IIS and set the TCP port on the Default Web Site to 64646 and the project loaded without error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [install IIS on your development machine](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725762.aspx).

Using IIS you'll also need to run Visual Studio in Admin Mode as well.

It is recommended that you use [IIS Express](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/28/introducing-iis-express.aspx) since it will allow you to run VS without Admin privileges.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install IIS and create the web site in IIS with the matching port number. Someone else created the visual studio web project to use IIS and configured it on their computer. Each person who opens the solution has to have all the websites configured in IIS manually.

You might consider creating a script that auto-creates them in the source repository. You can do it using AppCmd.exe (ADD SITE, ADD APPPOOL, LIST APPPOOL, LIST SITE) (%windir%\system32\inetsrv\AppCmd.exe).